# adb shell touch is not working

Tags: adb, file-system, shell

I am trying to force the timestamp of a specific file on my android device to a specific date.

when I run..

```
touch specific_file
```

it succeeds and sets the timestamp to the current time.

But if I run

```
touch -t 20170901.123456 specific_file
```

the command does not take, although it does not scream out an error. This is the exact format and argument structure that the version of touch I am running in Busybox suggests.

Is this just a bug?

Comment: In my busybox, doing `busybox touch -t 20170901.123456 specific_file` changes the file's timestamp to some data in 2018. Using toybox's `touch` (native to Android 6), the query throws me some error.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in BusyBox, try updating your BusyBox binary, reboot the device then try again.